# How can I search by two continuous rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, peoplesoft

Given the SQL table

```
id     date       employee_type  employee_level
1   10/01/2015        other            2
1   09/13/2011      full-time          1
1   09/25/2010       intern            1
2   09/25/2013      full-time          3
2   09/25/2011      full-time          2
2   09/25/2008      full-time          1
3   09/23/2015      full-time          5
3   09/23/2013      full-time          4
```

Is it possible to search for ids that have one row with employee_type "intern", and the row above it in the table (same id with later date) with employee_type "full-time".

In this case, id 1 meets my requirement.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you sorting it when you say "previous"?  By the `date` column?

Comment: There is no implied order of rows in a SQL table. What do you mean by "previous"? Do you mean the same id with an earlier date?

Comment: I don't believe the requirement is based on order of rows, rather it is based on a need for ids which has been both intern and full-time

Comment: why 3 records ? , base on your description ..it suppose to return only two rows, `employee_level = 2` will not be included because the type is `other`, or you mean when you encounter that sequence, you will return all id ?

Comment: @bitfiddler Thanks. By previous I mean same id with later date. The row above in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean the same id with the previous date, then you can use `lag()`, an ANSI standard function supported by most databases:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id in (select id
               from (select t.*,
                            lag(employee_type) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_et
                     from table t
                    ) tt
               where tt.employee_type = 'intern' and tt.prev_et = 'full-time'
              );
```

If your database doesn't support `lag()`, you can do something similar with correlated subqueries.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the question to make it more clear. I think using lag()  is the right way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the request isn't as described in the question; instead what you appear to be wanting is list all rows for folks who have been interns.

```
SELECT
      t1.*
FROM yourtable AS t1
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                  id
            FROM yourtable
            WHERE employee_type = 'intern'
      ) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
;
```

Alternatively you might be wanting only those folks who have been both 'intern' and 'full-time' in which case you could use the query below that uses a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT
      t1.*
FROM yourtable AS t1
      INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id
            FROM yourtable
            WHERE employee_type = 'intern'
                  OR employee_type = 'full-time'
            GROUP BY id
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employee_type) > 1
      ) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
;
```